# No winterbash-2015 hats visible on profile page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2015

While the winterbash-hats are visible on (f.ex.) academia.se, I can't see the snowflake on stackoverflow. Nevertheless according to meta-posts SO should participate. Is that a bug, or something else?

Comment: You need to enable it on Stack Overflow. It is automatically enabled on other sites.

Comment: Where can I enable it? I did not find that in my profile...

Comment: You don't see the snowflake on the topbar?

Comment: Hmm, this is weird, it indeed looks like the Winter Bash code isn't running for you on Stack Overflow, but on other sites. Do you have any extensions running that selectively block script downloads?

Comment: Yes, but the script only now showed up in policeman... Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in my case was enabling loading the external scripts with policeman (addon for Firefox).